# load data from csv file to table hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, beeline

Im new using hive,

table tb1 is created as below:

```
create external table tb1 
(id string,
name string, 
product string, 
depart string)
PARTITIONED BY (dt DATE);
```

I want to insert data in external tables using the command below:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/peoject010212/hive/data_tb1.csv' into table tb1 partition (dt='2022-03-12')
```

The data is inserted but in wrong format in the table. all the file is loaded in the first column.
the table tb1 columns are: id, name, product, depart, dt
the content of the file is:

```
12,xxx,yy,zz
13,xxy,yz,zt
```

Who can help me please?

Danke,

Comment: Pleas show your Hive table definition. Is is expecting comma-delimited data? If so, your CSV file doesn't have any commas, so each row is treated as one column. You also will need to remove its header before you upload it

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you ! can you please have a look i updated my question with  the extact content of file and table and the creation script. Thank you

Comment: and telll me if still not clear . Thank you

Comment: Seems fine, but you may need to change your table to have `FIELDS DELIMITED BY ','` and `STORED AS TEXT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a table like below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tb1 (
id int,
name string, 
product string, 
depart string) 
PARTITIONED BY (dt DATE)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```